# Touch keyboard not appearing in WinUI 3 app

Tags: c#, xaml, tablet, winui-3

I have a touch application that was originally written using the UWP framework and I've not ported it to WinUI3. Everything has gone well so far but when I use a TextBox and click on it **the touch Windows keyboard doesn't appear**.

After lots of experimentation I decided to try out the template that comes with VS 2022 for a packaged WinUI3 app. This app is very simple and I thought this would be a good starting point to figure out what I am doing wrong. Out of the box it just has a button that when clicked changes its text to "Clicked". This works fine. I then add a TextBox to the app and when I click it no keyboard comes up.

What I do know;

1. When I use other apps on the pc and click into a text box the keyboard comes up. For example, when pressing on Windows search, or when I use Edge and do a search it appears. It also appears when using VS.
2. There is no physical keyboard attached.
3. The device is in **Tablet mode**.

So there is nothing in the OS that seems to be the problem and the VS template doesn't work out of the box either.

I'm loathe to think this is a bug in WinUI3 as it seems fundamental.

Here is the template code:

```
<Window
    x:Class="TextBoxTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TextBoxTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
        <TextBox Width="200" Height="200"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should file a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6291